# How to maintain the zero potential at the connector end?

Tags: test-equipment

I am developing *Automated Test Equipment* (ATE), from the ATE, on the output connector there will be a some potential exists.

How to maintain the zero potential at the connector end, which goes to Test Article?

**Note:** Before connecting to Test Article connector end potential should be zero.

Comment: Please go into more detail to explain what your problem is including a block diagram, it is unclear at the moment. I belive what you are looking for is called a 'virtual ground'.

Comment: You need to add a schematic of the system, and the bit you're trying to make. The answer is probably 'remote sensing'.

Comment: Are you going to tell us the signal bandwidth, impedance, tolerance & noise environment.for stray capacitance and inductance?  This seems to be an EMI problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7S8jx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A latching current relay.*

How it works:

- With no load connected RLY1 turns off.
- When load is connected the ON button is pressed. This causes current to flow through RLY1 and its contact closes. ON can now be released and power will stay on.
- If the load is disconnected RLY1 will open again. The OFF button can be used to switch off power before disconnection.

RLY1 should be chosen with a coil current rating to match the load under test. The switch contacts also need to be rated for the load.

Comment: You did notice the OP is talking about an ATE? There are likely to be tens if not hundreds of test points. This is just not scalable, and won't work at signal levels.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I noticed that the OP didn't say much at all and the question is hopelessly vague. S/he could be testing electric kettles for all we know. My answer might prompt an improvement to the question.